# Python: Filtering a datastructure depended on columnvalue

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe structured like so:

```
DF1:
|'ID'|'Zone'|
|:---------:|
| 11 |  1   |
| 12 |  2   |
| 10 |  0   |


DF2:
|'ID'|'Time'|
|:---------:|
| 11 |   1  |
| 11 |   2  |
| 12 |   1  |
| 12 |   2  |
```

And I want to add a new column to DF2 named zone, that contain the correct value for which zone each ID belong to. See example below.

```
|'ID'|'Time'|'Zone'|
|:----------------:|
| 11 |   1  |   1  |
| 11 |   2  |   1  |
| 12 |   1  |   2  |
| 12 |   2  |   2  |
```

For this small example I have written some code that works fine, but I will like to use is on two large DF. So my qustion is, is there a more delicated (better) way to do this? My current code is:

```
df2 = np.empty([len(df2.index)]
for i in df2.index:
    for j in df.index:
        if df2['id'][i] == df1['id'][j]:
            df2.loc[i, 'zone'] = df1.loc[j, 'zone']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging) function to perform a join:

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID")
```

Where `on="ID"` indicates which is the reference column and must be present in both dataframes (if you want to join using columns with different names, it is also possible, just check the docs).

`merge` is also available [as a dataframe's method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) so you can alternatively call it as:

```py
df1.merge(df2, on="ID")
```

With exactly same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.merge(df2, how='right')

or 

df2.merge(df1,how='left')
```

joining df2 with df1 using ID columns

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice one liner

`df2["Zone"] = [df1.set_index("ID")["Zone"][df2["ID"][i]] for i in df2.index]`

Setting the index of df1 to its 'ID' column allows the values of df2's 'ID' column to act as indices, making the call a little simpler.